# Bootstrap - row keeps jumping 1 line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, html

I'm playing with bootstrap and am working with the scaffolding. I want three columns, but somehow every 'span' jumps one line. I can't figure out why.

My code:

```
<div class="footer">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <pre>
  <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span4">Span 4</div>
       <div class="span4">Span 4</div>
       <div class="span4">Span 4</div>
   </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span4">Span 4</div>
       <div class="span4">Span 4</div>
       <div class="span4">Span 4</div>
   </div>



</pre>
  </div>
```

And the undesired result:

[image: scaffolding-bootstrap]

Comment: It doesn't look like any of those divs are aligned, are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that `<pre>` is adding extra style, perhaps to the left and right of your row. If you take it out it should work fine. Check this [snippet](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ycsKb) (and the [result](http://cdpn.io/ycsKb)) that I made, I replaced `<pre>` with a div and I used the `well` class. Hope that helped. Btw, I also added the container class to center the page, you don't have to do that.